# Is there a way to see all of the cases i've ever worked in fogbugz

Tags: filter, filtering, case, fogbugz

Say we have the following case:

1. Jen Ninja (a Developer with an
   awesome last name) likes to look at
   the following list view filter:

   All open cases assigned to Jen Ninja with the status of Active
2. Jen Ninja gets assigned a bunch of
   cases (some of them bugs, some of
   them features).
3. Jen looks at her filtered list and
   see them.  No problem.
4. Jen Ninja bangs out all of her cases
   and they then get assigned to
   various QA people.
5. Two days before release, Jen's boss
   asks here "What were all of things
   you worked on?"
6. Jen has a decent memory, but would
   feel more comfortable seeing what
   Fogbugz says she worked on.

How does Jen change her filter so she can answer this question with confidence?

Comment: Contact FogCreek Software for support.

Comment: ha.  I thought about doing that, but i figured i'd ask the community before bugging them.

Comment: +1 to Chris ; too localized.. dont want to encourage such questions.. 1. such products/apps have their own tech support/forums which can provide better/any answers. 2. the next thing you know SO is flooded 'How do I do X in shrink wrapped product Y?'

Comment: I disagree...this is a technical question no different than asking how to configure IIS or set up a Web.Config file.  Will we soon close questions like that too, just telling people to go look it up on MSDN?

Comment: On the right are questions such as "Unhappy FogBugz user?" and "Can FogBugz track case dependencies?" - neither of which is marked "Closed". Why would this be any different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is surprisingly difficult.  Searching by name doesn't work as the "Assigned To" and "Resolved By", etc. items are not searched even though they are shown when you bring a case up on screen.  Typically, I (as a developer) am listed as the "Resolver" on each FogBugz case so the closest I've come is to run a search on all cases (Open and Closed) where I am listed as the person who resolved it.  In a separate search, I look for all Closed cases where I closed it (you cannot do both Resolved and Closed or you'll only gets those where I both Resolved and Closed it).

The only way I see to make this *easy* in FogBugz is for Jen to "Subscribe" to every case she works on.  If she does this, then it is very easy to generate the list: just show all cases to which she is subscribed.

Joel sometimes frequents these parts so perhaps you'll get him to comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the custom search syntax to create a custom filter

```
 editedby:me OR assignedto:me
```

I combined this with Active status to find any active cases I previously edited or has been assigned to me.

See [FogBugz Help](http://help.fogcreek.com/7480/search-syntax-and-the-search-axis?se_found=1)

Answer (score 0):

You might get what you're looking for by selecting Filter->Special->Viewed By->Me and combining it with Assigned To->Me and making sure that the cases are set to ALL.